# npm install myPackage -g, Error: Cannot find module 'commander'

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I am Chinese, my English is not good.

I submit a npm package,this package dependent on `commander`, i sure the `commander` had install.

Then i install my package, when i use it, the console show 'Error: Cannot find module 'commander', i'm confused.

this is code:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "commander": "^2.15.1",
    "download-git-repo": "^1.0.2",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.11",
    "inquirer": "^6.0.0",
    "log-symbols": "^2.2.0",
    "ora": "^2.1.0"
  }
```

when i npm install -g my package,the 'commander' could not be found:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpDzt.png

Comment: Did you try `npm i commander` ?

Comment: What do you get when you run `npm commander -v`

Comment: emm.. thank you for your answer, i have solved the problem.  the packages in the devDependencies is can't submit to npm,i transferred them to dependencies。